# What is the proper name given to MySQL's Linear Hash algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash, partitioning

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-linear-hash.html

I can't seem to find an equivalent on Wikipedia.

[Consistent Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) was the closest I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called 'linear hashing': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing

It has been used since the 80s to make hash tables that rehash incrementally as they grow.

Comment: The term "linear hash partitioning" used by MySQL is a bit confusing: linear hashing is indeed a technique to make tables that can progressively adapt their number of buckets to the data.
However, that linear hashing datastructure is not used in MySQL's algorithm for partitioning. They are only vaguely related (the assignment of bucket to the key is determined by the key some modulo power of 2).

Comment: It's described differently in the MySQL docs that OP linked to, but it's the same algorithm (partition = hash bucket).  The computations are all done based on the number of buckets, and no specific data structure is required.

Comment: Not really. I've read both the wikipedia article and the original paper 
http://infolab.cs.unipi.gr/pre-eclass/courses/db/db-post/readings/Litwin-VLDB80.pdf carefully. It's just not about the same thing:
linear hashing is a "datastructure" (Wikipedia), or equivalently, "a hashing in which the address space may grow or shrink dynamically". There is nothing of the kind in MySQL's linear hash algorithm. I certainly agree that in both cases the computations are done based on the number of bucket, and both involve some modulo with respect to a power of 2. But the relation stops there.

Comment: In other words, as far as I can see, both words refer to very different concepts.

Comment: In fact, you were *quite* right, the source code itself says the function is "computed accorded to the theory of linear hashing". 
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_partition.cc#L1372

I still believe that the connection is tenuous, but that's debatable. They probably mean that they took from linear hashing the idea of using a same hash function whatever the number of buckets, and adding a mask whose length depends on the number of buckets.